# Round number for label in MapServer

Tags: labeling, mapserver, expression

With MapServer, is it possible to use an expression to round a number for a label?

For example, my dataset has the float value 174.000000000 which I want to show in a label as 174.

I have tried a few mathematical expressions for a label, but, now think that MapServer may not accomodate mathematical expressions in labelling.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Certainly yes but is difficult to guess how to do it even it is somehow documented in https://www.mapserver.org/mapfile/expressions.html

The function to use is "tostring"

> tostring ( n1, “Format1” )
>
> uses “Format1” to format the number n1 (C style formatting - sprintf).

Example with field SQKM that contains areas in square kilometers with decimals. Notice also how you can add the unit into the label.

```
CLASS
      NAME "world"
      STYLE
        COLOR 58 132 59
        OUTLINECOLOR 30 30 30
      END # STYLE
      TEXT (tostring(([SQKM]),"%.0f")+" km2")
      LABEL
        COLOR  150 200 200
        FONT "sans"
        TYPE truetype
        SIZE 16
        POSITION AUTO
        PARTIALS FALSE
      END #LABEL
    END # CLASS
```

The result looks like this

[image]

It is possible to combine with math and show thousands of square kilometers with

```
TEXT (tostring(([SQKM]/1000),"%.0f"))
```